# How to validate email id of the orders placed in Opencart through an Android App

Tags: php, android, opencart

We are planning to make a licencing system for our Android App in which the User's(Android) email should be validated against the order placed in our Opencart store. In our Opencart store we will sell the subscription for our Android App and if the users purchased the subscription, it's email id get registered as order and their Android application get activated automatically (The same Gmail is used in the Android phone).

Please give some suggestions and logic to complete this work.

Answer (score 0):

I hope i have understood your problem,

So here is my simple solution.

Step1)
create an API which reads the information from the table which has complete information of all the subscribed users.

Step2)
Call this API in your android app by passing the email id which user enters as parameter, Allow the user to access your app if the user with the email id is subscribed. Don't allow otherwise.

Let me know if u get any doubts.